# Find the area of the region that lies inside $r=\sin(2\theta)$ and outside of $r=\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration, analytic-geometry, area, polar-coordinates

Find the area of the region that lies inside
$r= \sin(2\theta)$
and outside of
$r=\cos(2\theta)$
using polar coordinates.

Generally, I could use help setting up the integral in order to solve for the area of this region. I am having trouble understanding how to find the interval from a to b in order to integrate. I am also having trouble understanding how symmetry applies to the integral in this case.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

First you find the intersections between $\sin(2 \theta)$ and $\cos(2\theta)$

$ \sin(2 \theta) = \cos(2 \theta) $

Implies $ 2 \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4} \Rightarrow \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{8} $

Therefore, the required area is

$ \text{Area} = 4 (\frac{1}{2}) \displaystyle \int_{\frac{\pi}{8}}^{\frac{3\pi}{8}} (\sin^2(2\theta) - \cos^2(2\theta) ) d\theta = -2 \int_{\frac{\pi}{8}}^{\frac{3\pi}{8}} \cos(4 \theta)  d\theta\\ =\displaystyle - \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \cos(u)  du = -\dfrac{1}{2} \Bigg[ \sin(u) \Bigg]_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} = 1 $

Comment: Why do you have to multiply 4 by the integral? And how did you find 3pi/8 for the upper bound of the integral? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Fatima We multiply by $4$ since, by symmetry, the total area between the curves is four times the area between the curves in the first quadrant.  If $\sin(2\theta) = \cos(2\theta)$, then $\tan(2\theta) = 1 \implies 2\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Solving for theta yields $\theta = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{n\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  If $n = 0$, we get $\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$.  What value do you get for $\theta$ if $n = 1$?

Comment: $\dfrac{3 \pi}{8} = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{8} $